# HighCharts x-axis not displaying correctly

Tags: highcharts

I have folowing setup:

```
 scrollbar: {
     enabled: true,            
    },
```

and

```
xAxis: {
    min:0,
    max:10,
        ...
```

Its all fine I if a have more than 10 records that are being displayed. If I get less than 10 records I get this result.

[image: before clik]

when I click on the scroll bar I get the right chart.

[image: after]

Is the any solution for this problem, and can I hide the scroll bar if there less then 10 records available?

Comment: can you please provide a working jsfiddle where you can reproduce this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your `var length = data.length;` before creating chart and set `max: length < 10 ? length : 10`

Comment: Set scrollbar.enabled = false.

Comment: Is there any solution for reduce gap between columns if max size is 2 ?

Comment: You probably mean `series.pointPadding` option, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding).